# Is there a downside of installing kernel 3.19 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04

I'm thinking about updating kernel on my laptop, hoping that it will reduce overheating. Is there a downside to this? Has anyone tried?

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is no downsides with installing or updating to newer version of kernel but probably you won't reduce overheating problems.